# php try catch doesnt handle the error occured

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

i am usually using visual basic and i use try catch for avoiding the desktop application from exiting the application if error occured.

now i try on php the same thing "try catch", but it doesnt working, it doesnt catch the error, it looks like goto in vb, we must throw an exception to go to the catch part. am i right?

below is my code ...

```
<?php

function conn() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pass123";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
}


try {

while (true) {      
    conn();
    echo "-";
    sleep(5);
}

}

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

if this code run in vb, the app will first show message on catch part like "message: blabla" and then the app stop, but in php the error doesnt bring to the catch part.

can anyone explain this please?

Comment: Because no exception happened?

Comment: Instead you need this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: Thank you u_mulder, sorry for my bad explaination, what i mean is why php doesnt catch the error without throwing exception? but if php truely work like that, my opinion is try catch on php is just like GOTO syntax in VB ... :)

Comment: What error are you talking about? There's nothing to catch in your code, no Exception is thrown.